# PHP redirect in HTML assist

Tags: php, html

I'm looking assistance on the redirect of href.

In my php above the HTML code is this :

```
<?php
session_start();
$cid = $_SESSION['userID'];  
?>
```

In the HTML below it , is it possible for me to redirect them using a href?

For example:

```
<a href="<?php $cid.memberpage.net;?>"Only Now , Join now</a>
```

Is it possible to do so?
I need help thank you in advance.

Comment: Whats the exact url where you want your user to go ,is it inside $cid ?

Comment: @Subhanker , two page . page 1 when they register so the username is saved via session and they'll be redirect to page 2 where the session will be used.

Comment: what is memberpage.net ? and whats inside $cid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect your user in many ways..

**using php:**

```
<?php
$cid="http://your.awesome.site/page.php";
header('Location: '.$cid);
?>
```

or using attribute

```
<a href="<?=$cid;?>"Only Now , Join now</a>
```

or automatically refresh in n sec

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="n; URL='<?=$cid;?>'"><!-- replace n with number of sec you want your user to stay on this page -->
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean by redirect them using a href?

You can always use:

```
<?php
  header('Location: '.$cid.'memberpage.net');
?>
```

or in the href (which wont redirect automatically), You will need to echo first...

```
<a href="<?php echo $cid.'memberpage.net';?>"Only Now , Join now</a>
```

Comment: It gives something like this www.something.com/start/memberpage.net, it's not working thou

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dot notation in PHP,  well, there might be a chance, $_SESSION can handle as array and populating links but it's not recommended and best practice. The best ways is passing URL from Controller (If you are using MVC architecture, I assume) or directly passing value or load from configuration files.

Comment: In PHP, the dot operator is for concatenation.

Comment: missing $ in other variable is getting no where and misleading to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it will redirect to the url you need.

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $cid.'.memberpage.net';?>"Only Now , Join now</a>
```